# MVC NET - Keep simple data between controllers

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm working on a simple project which is based on the popular ContosoUniveristy tutorial. I want to extend some of the functionalities present in this tutorial.

I have created a table named School where I keep each schools properties like address, phone number, courses, students and so on. Later I added a foreignKey property named SchoolID to student, course and few other tables.

I have SchoolIndex page with basic layout view where all the schools are listed and user can click one to go to the details page. This details page has a _DitLayout layout with additional menu on the left where one can find links to appropriate informations e.g. contact, courses, students (like the ones stored in School table). _DitLayout is shared by all the contact, courses and students views.

Here I have a problem. When I click school on the SchoolIndex page I want the links in the menu on the left to point to this particular school properties. To do that I would have to somehow pass SchoolID to the layout page (not a good idea?). The other way is to somehow store the SchoolID when running trough views, controllers and actions. So that in the controller i could write

```
  public class SchoolController : Controller
  {
     private SchoolContext db = new SchoolContext();

     public ActionResult Contact()
     {

        int ID  = //here I pass SchoolID;

        // I fetch school from the database
        SchoolModel school = db.School.Find(ID);

        //and I map the properties to the ViewModel
        ContactViewModel contact = new ContactViewModel();
        contact.Address = school.Address;
        contact.Phone = school.Phone;
        //etc.

        return View(contact);
     }
   }
```

**Question is:** How can I pass or store SchoolID between controllers? YES I need to pass ID not only between actions but also between controllers.

I thought that maybe i could store this ID in the cookie. Is it a good idea? Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store data, without keeping it inside the URL (or HTTP request), then you would have to save it either in Session or Cookie.

Personally I would modify the MVC routing to incorporate the school id.

eg: `/{schoolId}/{controller}/{action}`.

This way schoolId will be available in any action, regardless of the controller.

Comment: Thanks Nsevens. I wil try your solution right away.

Comment: Nsevens I can't wrap my head around it. If I have a route pattern like this url: "{schoolID}/{controller}/{action}/{id}" then how should I write my controller and for example Html.ActionLink() in the view to make this work?

Comment: @Arthur you can have an action method `public ActionResult All(int schoolID)` in controller `NewsController`, which in turn can be called by an actionlink `@Html.ActionLink("View school news", "All", "News", new RouteValueDictionary(new { schoolID = <<YOUR_SCHOOL_ID>> }))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Session object or TempData to pass data between controllers.

```
public class SchoolController : Controller
{
    private SchoolContext db = new SchoolContext();

    public ActionResult Contact()
    {
        int ID  = TempData["SchoolID"];

        // I fetch school from the database
        SchoolModel school = db.School.Find(ID);

        //and I map the properties to the ViewModel
        ContactViewModel contact = new ContactViewModel();
        contact.Address = school.Address;
        contact.Phone = school.Phone;
        //etc.

        return View(contact);
    }
}

public class OtherController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult School(int id)
    {
        TempData["SchoolID"] = id;

        return RedirectToAction("/School/Contact");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sousuke. I also had this thought but I read that sesions and TempData have security drawbacks so I'll leave it as a second choice.